# How can I temporarily change the tmp directory Perl uses?

Tags: perl, temp, temporary-directory

Some libraries I use seem to write stuff to `/tmp`.

I would like to change the 'temporary' directory location my script (and all the imported libraries) uses to `/new/tmp/location`. Needless to say, I don't want to effect anything outside my script (so e.g remounting `/tmp` is not an option).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many libraries will create temporary files in the directory specified by the TMPDIR environment variable, if it is set.  Give it a try; if that doesn't help, you're going to have to say more about what libraries you are wanting to affect.